# How to make multiple MongoDB trips efficiently

Tags: node.js, mongodb

general node mongodb question here.

I have this function:

```
static addSpaceToCreator = ( userId, spaceId, callback ) => {
        const db = getDb();
        db.collection( process.env.SPACECOLLECTION ).updateOne( { _id: ObjectId( spaceId ) }, { $push: { challengers: ObjectId( userId ) } } );
        db.collection( process.env.USERSCOLLECTION ).updateOne( { _id: ObjectId( userId ) }, { $push: { spaces: ObjectId( spaceId ) } } ).then( r => callback( r ) ).catch( e => callback( e ) );
    };
```

Question: 
Is there a better way of making multiple changes like this? I cannot use Bulk because the documents are in different collections. Even if i didn't have a callback, is there a better way of doing 2 .collection trips?

Thank you for your time

Comment: By using `Promise.all` to dispatch parallel queries.

Comment: So make the function async, await the db promise into each variable (res1, res2), and then at the bottom, have promise.all(res1,res2) and in that, return what is needed?

Comment: You don't need `async` nor `await`. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for the result of *parallel* queries, like so:

```
static addSpaceToCreator = ( userId, spaceId ) => {
    const db = getDb();

    return Promise.all([
      db.collection( process.env.SPACECOLLECTION ).updateOne( { _id: ObjectId( spaceId ) }, { $push: { challengers: ObjectId( userId ) } } ),
      db.collection( process.env.USERSCOLLECTION ).updateOne( { _id: ObjectId( userId ) }, { $push: { spaces: ObjectId( spaceId ) } } ));
    ]);
};
```

and use it like so:

```
await addSpaceToCreator(4, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes perfect sense!